# "Complex" MySql request, getting some columns associated with MIN and MAX values in the same request

Tags: mysql, sql

For example I have a dataset as below:

```
id, idPro, mesure2, mesure3, date
'6067', '1', '9.0', '29.3', '2013-11-17 12:48:39'
'6061', '1', '7.3', '30.3', '2013-11-17 15:20:12'
'6068', '2', '7.0', '29.3', '2013-11-17 12:48:39'
'6062', '2', '9.0', '25.3', '2013-11-17 15:20:12'
'6069', '3', '7.6', '29.0', '2013-11-17 12:48:39'
'6063', '3', '7.5', '27.0', '2013-11-17 15:20:12'
'6070', '4', '8.9', '29.1', '2013-11-17 12:48:39'
'6064', '4', '9.1', '23.1', '2013-11-17 15:20:12'
'6071', '5', '9.4', '28.9', '2013-11-17 12:48:39'
'6065', '5', '5.4', '30.9', '2013-11-17 15:20:12'
'6072', '6', '9.3', '28.9', '2013-11-17 12:48:39'
'6066', '6', '9.1', '24.9', '2013-11-17 15:20:12'
```

I want to output a table that have the minimal and maximal value of "mesure2" and "mesure3" grouped by idPro+Date and the time where those minimal and maximal value appeared.
So it should output something like:

```
idPro, mesureMin, dateMinMesure, mesureMax, timeMaxMesure, mesureType, date
'1', '7.3', '2013-11-17 12:48:39', '9.0', '2013-11-17 12:48:39', 'mesure2', '2013-11-17'
'1', '29.3', '2013-11-17 12:48:39', '30.3', '2013-11-17 15:20:12', 'mesure3', '2013-11-17'
'2', '7.0', '2013-11-17 12:48:39', '9.0', '2013-11-17 15:20:12', 'mesure2', '2013-11-17'
'2', '29.3', '2013-11-17 12:48:39', '25.3', '2013-11-17 15:20:12', 'mesure3', '2013-11-17'
...
```

Actually, I make a request that output the minimal and maximal value of each day for each mesure type (mesure2 or mesure3) and then I do other requests to get the date of each mesure. (I use php, and I build the request with
 `WHERE mesure2 = $valueReturnedByTheFirstRequest AND date LIKE '%2013-11-17%'`
)
But this is a lot of sql requests, I'm looking for a way to output something similar in 1 query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is MySql. And using it from PHP

Comment: isnt 9.4 and 5.4 are max and min mesure for mesure 2

Comment: Nope, because you have to group by idPro, min and max per idPro per day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT date,
       idpro,
       mesureType,
       mesureMin,
       ( SELECT min(t.date) FROM table1 t
         WHERE mesure2 = mesureMin
             AND t.idpro = x1.idpro
             AND x1.date = date( t.date )
        ) dateMinMesure ,
       mesureMax,
       ( SELECT min(t.date) FROM table1 t
         WHERE mesure2 = mesureMax
             AND t.idpro = x1.idpro
             AND x1.date = date( t.date )
        ) dateMaxMesure 
FROM( 
  SELECT date(date) `date`,
         idpro,
         'measure2' mesureType,
         min( mesure2 ) mesureMin,
         max( mesure2 ) mesureMax
  FROM table1 
  GROUP BY date(date), idpro, mesureType
) x1
UNION ALL
SELECT date,
       idpro,
       mesureType,
       mesureMin,
       ( SELECT min(t.date) FROM table1 t
         WHERE mesure3 = mesureMin
             AND t.idpro = x1.idpro
             AND x1.date = date( t.date )
        ) dateMinMesure ,
       mesureMax,
       ( SELECT min(t.date) FROM table1 t
         WHERE mesure3 = mesureMax
             AND t.idpro = x1.idpro
             AND x1.date = date( t.date )
        ) dateMaxMesure 
FROM( 
  SELECT date(date) date,
         idpro,
         'measure3' mesureType,
         min( mesure3 ) mesureMin,
         max( mesure3 ) mesureMax
  FROM table1 
  GROUP BY date(date), idpro, mesureType
) x1
ORDER BY date, idpro, mesuretype
```

demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/daa51/14